# Merging single level DataFrame with 3-level DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Single-level DataFrame:

```
   data1 = {'Sr.No.': Sr_no,
     'CompanyNames': Company_Names,
     'YourChoice1': Your_Choice,
     'YourChoice2': Your_Choice}

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = pd.Index(['Sr.No.', 'CompanyNames','YourChoice1','YourChoice2'], name='key'))
```

Output of single-level dataframe in csv file:

[image]

3-level dataframe:

```
   form = {'I1': {'F1': {'PD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   'CD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

            'F2': {'PD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   'CD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

            'F3': {'PD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   'CD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}
            },


     'I2': {'F1': {'PD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   'CD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']},

            'F2': {'PD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   'CD': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}
            }
     }

   headers,values,data = CSV_trial.DATA(form)
   cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headers, names=['ind','field','data'])
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Output of 3-level dataframe in csv file:
[image]

I want to merge these dataframe as df1 on left and df2 on right...

Desired Output:
[image]
Can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to transform the single-layer df into a 3-level, then concat two df's of the same structure.

Importing necessary packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Creating a native 3-level index. You can read it from a csv, xml, etc.

```
native_lvl_3_index_tup = [('A','foo1', 1), ('A','foo2', 3),
     ('B','foo1', 1), ('B','foo2', 3),
     ('C','foo1', 1), ('C','foo2', 3)]

variables = [33871648, 37253956,
           18976457, 19378102,
           20851820, 25145561]

native_lvl_3_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(native_lvl_3_index_tup)
```

Function, *converting native single-level index to a 3-level*:

```
def single_to_3_lvl(single_index_list,val_lvl_0,val_lvl_1):
    multiindex_tuple = [(val_lvl_0,val_lvl_1,i) for i in single_index_list]
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(multiindex_tuple)
```

Use this function to get an artificial 3-level index:

```
single_index = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
artificial_multiindex = single_to_3_lvl(single_index,'A','B')
```

Creating dataframes, transposing to move multiindex to columns (as in the question):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(variables,artificial_multiindex).T 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(variables,native_lvl_3_index).T
```

I used the same variables in the dataframes. You can manipulate the concatenation by setting  `join='outer' or 'inner'` in the `pd.concat()`

```
result = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis = 1)
```

Variable **result** contains the concatenated dataframes. If You have a single-level indexed dataframe, You can reindex it:

```
single_level_df = pd.DataFrame(single_index,variables)
reindexed = single_level_df.reindex(artificial_multiindex).T
```

Again, I do transposing (.T) to work with columns. It can be setup differently when creating dataframes.

Hope my answer helped. 
I used some code from the link: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html